# Select2 doesn't work when embedded in a bootstrap5 modal

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2, bootstrap5-modal

input of select2 loses focus in bootstrap5 modal, focus is made to another element (input tag)

intente con
$timeout(function(){$('#cmbPosition').select2({ dropdownParent: $('#addClient')});},1500);
y  eliminando el tabindex='-1' del modal